# Project run issue in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

When i change the code into my Flash Builder 4.5 project and hit run the output doesn't show the new result but the old one, only after a while the new result is showed on subsequent project runnings. Has anybody encounter this problem? Are there some hidden settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have the project set to build automatically.  ( Either that or that you have manually rebuilt the project after changing code).

Second, be sure to clear the relevant browser data as appropriate.

Third, In the earlier days of Flex, I found that if I re-compile code while there is an active debug session; it often doesn't refresh and would need a formal project "clean" after shutting down all my browsers, and restarting Flash Builder.  So, that may also apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a spot old but if you are testing in a browser you might want to refresh or clear your cache so the browser has to get the new data and not just rely on what it had loaded before.